# Show that: $\langle M, W\rangle \leq \sqrt 2 \delta \|W\|_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $M$ be a matrix with rank at most 2 and with bounded frobenius norm: $\|M\|_F \leq \delta$ for some constant $\delta$. Show the following bound:

$$\sup_M\langle M, W \rangle \leq \sqrt 2 \delta \|W\|_2$$

I am confused where the $\sqrt 2$ is coming from since it's easy to show that by considering the SVD of W, the LHS is equivalent to :

$$\sup_M \langle M, \Sigma\rangle$$

where $\Sigma$ is the matrix of singular values of $W$. Of course, the supremum is met when $M$ is the matrix which is $\delta$ along the maximum singular value. So the following upper bound holds:

$$\leq \delta \|W\|_2$$

Comment: Why "of course"?

Comment: What if $W = I$, $M = \operatorname{diag}({\delta \over \sqrt{2}}, {\delta \over \sqrt{2}}, 0,...)$?

Comment: Right, that doesn't seem to be true actually. Consider the example where $W$ is the 2x2 identity. It is better to place weight along the diagonal to get a supremum of $\sqrt 2 \delta$.

Comment: Thanks copper hat i see that now. And this example shows we can upperbound by considering the case of repeated singular values where we get $\delta/2\sigma$ contribution for each repetition. Which gives the result. Ill clean this up